# error with javascript: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error with my javascript: "missing ; before statement".

I'm trying to read in a date, add 6 months onto the date if it meets a certain criteria ( joiner type in this case) and if not just return that date.

I can't see whats wrong here, it must be something small, any ideas??

Thanks!

```
function checkenddate(Par) {
   var array = Par.split("!!");

   var usermskey = array[0];
   var date = array[1];
   var joinertype = array[2];

   saprep = UserFunc.uGetConstant("glb.REPOSITORY_ECC");
   attr1 = "Z_VALIDTO" + saprep;

   uWarning("Attribute: " + attr1);

   if (date == null && joinertype.equals("Contractor"))
   {
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       Calender c = Calender.getInstance();
       c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
       c.add(Calender.MONTH, 6);
       enddate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

       uWarning("End Date:" + enddate);

       OutString = uIS_SetValue(usermskey, 0, attr1, enddate);

       return enddate;
   } else {
       OutString = uIS_SetValue(usermskey, 0, attr1, date);
       return date;
   }
 }
```

Comment: **Which line** throws that error?

Comment: It appears you're confusing Java and JavaScript -- see [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: See also `Calender c = Calender.getInstance();` as well as the answers below.

Comment: I dont get a line that throws an error, just the error: missing ; before statement............. Andy is there something wrong with the way im declaring a Calender?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats not valid javascript. You can't have typed variables such as `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new blah()`. Change your types to `var` and it will work as expected.

```
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
var c = Calender.getInstance();
```

Comment: There are more variables in need of that correction: saprep, attr1, and enddate, unless they're defined out of the function

Comment: I tried declaring the variables in this function, changing the simpledateformat type to "var" but no luck...                                            Failed running function in string "$FUNCTION.checkenddate(285342!!2015-04-29!!Contractor)$$". Marking entry as failed. Exception was: org.mozilla.javascript.NotAFunctionException: glanbia_checkenddate(285342!!2015-04-29!!Contractor)

Comment: also changed the calender type but getting a new error...............Executing checkenddate(285343!!2015-04-28!!Contractor) got RuntimeException - undefined: "SimpleDateFormat" is not defined. HINT: Check line 18 in the script glanbia_checkenddate                  looks like i need to change the delcaring of the SimpleDateFormat??

Comment: Looks like i just needed to import the java classes...works like a charm! thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you declare a JS variable:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You need this instead:

```
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I would recommend using one of the linting tools online (e.g. JSHint or JSLint) to help track down these issues - very handy.

Comment: This answer half correct! test your code and give answer!

Comment: tried this but no luck! still the same error message unfortunately